# git undo commited file in current branch

Tags: git, github

I googled but still could not find right and easy answer how to do following:
I'm working on my branch and committed and pushed file1.txt many commits ago. But I don't actually want this file in my open PR. What is the easiest way to do that?
I tried `git rm` and `git rm --cached` but it remove file, but I want only undo whatever was committed before

Answer (score 1):

If you already pushed it you need to rewrite the entire history of commits and then do a forced push (normally you are not allowed to rewrite history)

Also, if you do this, make sure no-one else has this branch checked out and have changes. If they do and you destroy the history they will have a harder time recovering.

If you'd like to go ahead, github has a great guide or this exact use case over at https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Andreas Wederbrand, if you are not concerned about the rewrite the entire history of commits then switch to the branch from where the pull request is created, get the commit-id, reset it and push to remote, as follow:

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
git add -m "Revert commit for file file1.txt"
git push origin <branch-name>
```

Edit: As mentioned by @Todd `--hard` will throw away the entire commit.

If commit consists of changes other than `file1.txt` then checkout the file from the branch from where the pull request is created and push to remote as follows:

```
git checkout <desired-branch> -- path/to/file1.txt
git add -m "Revert commit for file file1.txt"
git push origin <branch-name>
```

Comment: Be careful with the `--hard` option as that assumes you want to throw away the entire commit. There might be other changes on that commit that you'd like to retain.

Comment: @Arpit If I do `git reset --hard` it removes whole commit, but I don't want it. I have other files there

Comment: Note that none of these suggestions will remove the file from the older commits. If the file contains sensitive data you need to rewrite EVERY commit since it was introduced.

Comment: @IlyaG I agree with @Andreas Wederbrand, if `file1.txt` has sensitive data then follow the step suggested by him, as above suggestions will just rewrite the `file1.txt` and not delete the history associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout an old version of the file:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <file>
```

Then commit it:

```
git commit
```

Done

If you want to delete the file, just delete it in the file system followed by:

```
git rm <file>
git commit
```

Done